# Show that a sequence is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let  $\delta>0$,$f(x)=\frac{1}{5}x+x^{1+\delta}$.Let $x_0>0$,define $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.How to show that $\{5^nx_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded sequence for all sufficiently small $x_0$?It seems quite obvious that this is true but I can't prove it rigorously.Can someone help me with this?

Comment: if you write $x_n$ explicitly ,you see that it is bounded by the sum of two geometric series..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general. But as you say, for $x_0$ small enough, it is true.

Take 
$$
x_0\leq \left( \frac{4}{5}\right)^{1/\delta}.
$$
Then a quick study of $f$ and an induction show that $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$, hence it converges to the unique fixed point of $f$, that is
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_n=0.
$$

It follows that
$$
x_n=x_{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}+x_{n-1}^\delta \right)\leq rx_{n-1}
$$
with 
$$
r=\frac{1}{5}+x_0^\delta .
$$

An easy induction shows that
$$
x_n\leq r^nx_0\leq r^n
$$
for all $n$.

Now observe that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{5}+x^\delta\right)^{1+\delta}<\frac{1}{5}$.

So we take $x_0>0$ small enough to have
$$
5r^{1+\delta}<1.
$$

Now for all $n$, we have
$$
0\leq 5^nx_n-5^{n-1}x_{n-1}=5^nx_{n-1}^{1+\delta}\leq 5(5r^{1+\delta})^{n-1}.
$$

Since the geometric series $\sum (5r^{1+\delta})^{n-1}$ converges, $\sum 5^nx_n-5^{n-1}x_{n-1}$ converges by comparison.

So the sequence
$$
5^kx_k=x_0+\sum_{n=1}^k 5^nx_n-5^{n-1}x_{n-1}
$$
converges.

In particular, the sequence $5^kx_k$ is bounded.

Comment: @Ben Let me know if you agree with my argument. I hope it helps.

Comment: your argument is good.thank you.